# If I delete a Windows Drive, Can I use that space to Install Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I current have Ubuntu Installed using Wubi under C:/ drive. Im on Ubuntu 11.10. Im planning a full reinstall of Ubuntu 12.04, but this time without Wubi.

I want to install Ubuntu on a Single Drive, like D:/ or G:/

Can I do that ? If I delete and make some unallocated space can I use that to Install Ubuntu ?

More Info :

Five Partitions

C: 135

D: 50

E: 50

F: 180

G: 50

Gparted shows I have Primary ntfs 135 and other 330 as extended.

I have Windows 7 x64

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "full reinstall of ubuntu"? That you are going to remove windows or that you are planning to uninstall 11.10 and install 12.04 in another partition?

Comment: @harisibrahimkv: I mean not to Upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 LTS rather Completely Uninstall Ubuntu 11.10 and then Install 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Alright. I hope my answer helps you then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install ubuntu on any partition. I don't see the actual meaning of your question though. If you are afraid that while installing ubuntu it will wipe out your entire Hard disk, then no. It won't wipe out your entire hard disk unless you select the option "Use the complete hard disk for installation" during the installation steps of ubuntu.

You can make some unallocated space (keep in mind that your hard disk can have only four primary partitions. So if there are already four, make this unallocated space within the extended partition) and install ubuntu there. Attaching an image of my hard disk:

[image]

Comment: How you create four Primary Partitions ? I have upgraded win 7 from XP and all those partitioned created While Installing XP. Im seeing slight preformance loss while booting up on Ubuntu and I think Wubi is the cause. Thats why this time I want to do a installation on a single partition. Also I want to give atleast 50 GB to Linux Drive.

Comment: Does all of your D:, E:, G: and F: drives contain data on them?

Comment: Yes ! more or less. I have added a image, see that.

Comment: Okay, here goes. Since you want to give 50GB for Ubuntu, we will resize your 180GB drive (/dev/sda7/). Use Gparted, right click on /dev/sda7 and shrink (move/resize) it to 120GB so that the already used up 40GB will be within that 120GB and you will have 60GB unallocated space. Once you have done this, you can install your ubuntu in that 60GB without any problems. Any more doubts?

Comment: Just one. What will happen all the data I already have in 180 GB ? Should I transfer them to some other drive ? And does it gonna have any other effect on Windows ?(like system instability)

Comment: All the data that you have in the 180GB drive will be in the 120GB drive after you perform the resize. So don't worry about that. As for an installation of ubuntu alongside windows affecting Windows itself, I haven't experienced such a situation in my life yet. :) So go for it.

Comment: Thanks. I will inform you about the output here. Keep visiting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; You can made it in the installation process. When prompted to choose how do you want to install Ubuntu, choose manually and repartition your disks as you want.

IMPORTANT: Do backup of important data first anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Just run the installation from an Ubuntu CD or DVD, and follow the on-screen instructions. You will see an option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows -- choose that option and Ubuntu should automatically choose the partition for you and install Ubuntu on it.
(This assumes you have already deleted the partions so that they show up as unallocated space in gparted.)

Comment: @Anton: Do you mean Ubuntu will use that Unallocated Space and leave my other drives untouched ?

Comment: Yup, it will  not cause any harm to existing data

Comment: This should work, and I've done it myself.  However, please make sure you have a backup of important data to another device first.