# How can I dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

Can you explain, How can I dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 7. I'm using Windows 7 and I want to install 12.04.

Comment: Please refer to the answer of this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/129399/if-i-delete-a-windows-drive-can-i-use-that-space-to-install-ubuntu/129413#129413

Answer (score 0):

See this page http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop
In the Installation type page, Ubuntu installer will automatically detect your pre-installed Windows and give you an option to install it alongside Windows 7. Select that option. After that allocate disk space for Ubuntu. If you want to completely move to Ubuntu, I would recommend giving some 50 GBs to it; Otherwise 10 GB is good.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way to install Ubuntu on a PC already having Win7!
If U Wish to Burn from CD U can do it or U can use Ur Pendrive too!

- Burning from Disk - Link Given above
- Install when running Windows - [Installing Ubuntu with the Windows installer : Instructions when downloading from IE on Windows!](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows)