# Ubuntu installation instead of Windows 7

Tags: system-installation, partitioning

I am  an Ubuntu newbie user. I used Ubuntu on a virtual machine and I liked it very much. Now I want to install it instead of Windows 7 on ''C'' drive.
Will that format my other drives too?

Comment: No, it won't unless you tell it during installation. See here also:http://askubuntu.com/questions/129399/if-i-delete-a-windows-drive-can-i-use-that-space-to-install-ubuntu?rq=1  Best luck with Ubuntu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is: yes, it will unless you tell it not to.

Checking "Replace Windows with Ubuntu" will erase all Windows partitions. If you want to keep those (ie. D:, E:) except C: choose "manual" and remove C: yourself and then pick the unallocated space.

We expect you to create a backup of your important documents (at the least those documents you can not re-download) before you start messing with partitions. A mistake is made very quickly and misreading the installer options during partitioning will kill your data.