# Ubuntu 12.10 installer doesn't recognize Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 on my Sony Vaio laptop, which already has Windows 7 on it, so I can dual boot. But, when I tried, I got

> This computer currently has no detected operating system

I'm installing Ubuntu from my USB drive. Is this normal?

Comment: Maybe related: [“Install alongside” option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using “Something Else”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this message, you might have to use a tool such as gparted to solve the problem (assuming you know what you're doing). This basically gives you the ability to view your disk partitions and delete or modify existing ones.

Worst case scenario, you will need to reformat into NTFS again for Windows, and then install windows again as well as Ubuntu. However, search askubuntu for more answers that might be simpler than mine.

Here is the link

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Im fighting with this also, the problem is with the boot config in the bios (UEFI) you have to change to legacy (at least in my SVS1511v9).
Im struggling because the 12.10 install stalls before reaching partition manager, ans 12.04 gives 141 error in partition manager.