# Will all the drives be formatted if I replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu?

Tags: drive, format

Hello I am a Windows 7 user and I am planning to replace it by Ubuntu. I have three drives and windows 7 is installed in drive C. I just want to know that weather all my drives will be formatted while replacing it with Ubuntu or only C drive (where my Windows 7 is currently installed)?

Comment: It is not clear which system is being replaced. Which do have installed presently and which do you want to install?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you choose the **Replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu** option, all of your hard disk (all of your partitions) will be **completely formatted and deleted**, and new partitions will be created for Ubuntu.

If you wish to delete only the C drive (where Windows is installed), and install Ubuntu there, you'll need to choose the **Something Else** option, and give the C drive a mount point of `/`.

For more information on the Something Else option, see this question: ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/163962/52726)

Answer (score 1):

To replace Windows with Ubuntu, once you get to the Installation Type screen, you would choose Replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu, or Something else

[image]

Choosing Something else, will give you the option to choose the partition that you want to use.  Keep in mind that Ubuntu lists drives different than windows.  So `C drive` would be `Sda` would be the first physical drive, `Sda1` would be the first partition on the first physical drive, `Sda2` would be the second partition on the first physical drive, ans so on.  `Sdb` would be the second physical drive, `Sdc` would be the third physical drive, and so on.  So in your case `C drive` (providing that you have one partition on it) would be `Sda`, now if you only have one physical drive with multiple partitions, then your `C drive` would be `Sda1`.  Once you determine the right drive, you would delete the partition, and create 2 Ubuntu partitions.  A partition mounted as `/`, and a `Swap` partition.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its actually depends upon where you are installing and how are you installing.

for example [image]

In the above image if you choose 1st option it will install the Ubuntu and windows 7 with out any modifications to your system by choosing a safe automatic partition process with 100% success rate.

If you choose the 2nd option then your windows partition will be formatted and Ubuntu will use that partition for the installation.I mean your windows will lost.

If you choose the 3rd option then there you can specify the partition manually. so you can give a specific drive for Ubuntu installation.

usually 90% of the users will give the 3rd choice.

now choice is up to you.