# How to Install Ubuntu by replacing Windows but without formatting other partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I'm using Windows 7 on my PC (1 GB RAM,160 GB HDD).
I want to **install Ubuntu and remove Windows 7**
I have Partitioned my PC into 2 drives , C  Drive - 40 GB and D Drive - 120 GB.
I want to install Ubuntu on the C drive **without formatting D drive** so how can I do that?
I know that I will have to select the **Something Else** option when the Installation Type Screen appears but I don't know how to proceed from there.
[My question looks kinda similar to this question but its not the same.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340786/will-all-the-drives-be-formatted-if-i-replace-windows-7-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Actually it's very simple to do that**

I'll start from the **something else** option because you are asking about that.

- Click **something else** and then choose <kbd>Continue</kbd>
- A window will open something like:

  [image]

  in your case it would be different and will display two partitions **sda1** and **sda2** under **sda**. And also `the free space would be at the beginning` ;)
- Select **sda1** and click Delete it will free the space at the beginning.(The picture is just for help, it is at the last in the picture).
- Then again select the free space that you've made free and click <kbd>Add</kbd>. A window will open something like:

  [image: image2]

  choose the exact value except the size. You have to set the size according to your need and you've to leave some size for **Swap** space. So I suggest you to leave `4GB` for **Swap**. So allocate around `36 GB` of size, click <kbd>Ok</kbd>
- In the next step again some free space will be left, so select that and again click <kbd>Add</kbd> button. this time you have to allocate all the free left space to **Swap**. You have to chose **Use as**: option in order to assign that as **Swap**.
- That's all you have to do. While highlighting the `sda1` to which you are going to install `Ubuntu` just click <kbd>Install Now</kbd> button.

Comment: ok @SauravKumar so you have solved my problem upto 90% but I still do have few Queries
1. Which one should between Physical and Logical for C drive(sda1) ?
2. Which File System Should I choose for C Drive(sda1) like ext4,ext3,NTFS or something else ?
3. Which mount point should I select for C Drive(sda1) ? I think I should choose "/" Root Directory as my Mount point for C Drive
4. What is the minimum  amount of Swap Area required ? As I have only 1 GB RAM and 160 GB HDD so tell me least required Swap space ? and for swap space which one should I choose between Physical / Logical Partition ?

Comment: Chose `Primary` for `sda1` and `Ext4` file system. The mount point you have to select is the same as shown in the picture. and the maximum swap you have to use is 1GB for 1GB RAM. and logical partition you have for `Swap`