# Only Erease Disk and Something else options when installing Ubuntu along Windows 8

Tags: system-installation

How do I install Ubuntu 13.10 and dual boot Windows 8.1 pro?  When I boot the installation USB I only get 2 options: "Erase disk and install Ubuntu 13.10", or "Something else".  I tried "something else" but I don't know how to install it on a partition.

Comment: I reinstalled Windows 8 and it still didn't find it.  I just then created the partions my self and it works!

Comment: Congrats on getting it solved, can you add that as an answer? :)

Comment: Related: [How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows 7 using “Something Else”?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-7-using-something-else), [How to get Ubuntu installer to sense Windows 8.1 as an OS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/434709/how-to-get-ubuntu-installer-to-sense-windows-8-1-as-an-os)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose **something else** option it will directs you to select the partition in which you want to install ubuntu.And also force you to choose the linux-swap partition size.

Please allocate *linux-swap* partition size by following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) link.

Comment: But some may require that.

Comment: @Braiam It's always best to start with a SWAP partition than have to make one later IMO.

Comment: @Braiam yes, you are correct.I edited my answer to follow the link for allocating swap size.You can setup a swap file easily, but think about a Ubuntu noob user.It's so hard for them.

Comment: @Braiam That's in your case. You must remember that *you* are a geek. Not everyone else is. Telling them they don't need SWAP and it's "easy" to get it later isn't a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: @Braiam Unless you want to hibernate. I know lots of people who do that on a regular basis. Or you have little RAM. I know lots of people that have little RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 13.10 detected win8 but, i had to shrink win8 partition before:
http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/11/shrink-resize-partitions-in-windows-8/
I think ubuntu only detects win8 when there's free space without partition.