# How to get Ubuntu installer to sense Windows 8.1 as an OS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

When I go to install Ubuntu so I can dual boot Ubuntu with windows 8.1 on my Toshiba Satellite C55 the Ubuntu installer does not sense My pre-installed windows 8.

I referred to these guides: [UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) and [installing Ubuntu on pre-installed-windows8 64bit system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported), but the first link suggests, to use the `install Ubuntu along side`option or make an EFI partition however it also says to only have one EFI partition on the hard drive and windows is in an EFI Partition.

- So I need to know how to Get Ubuntu to sense windows 8.1 or how to manually partition the hard drive so I can dual boot. Just so you know I have a Kubuntu 13.10 on a disk, Ubuntu 13.10 on a disk, and Ubuntu 12.04 on a disk.

If you need any more tech specifications I can give them to you.

Comment: Related: [How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows 7 using “Something Else”?](http://askubuntu.com/q/163962/22949) (*If* they end up being considered duplicates--which I think is likely the best thing to do--then we should generalize the title of the master question and ask moderators to merge answers, since [the answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/434781/22949) appears quite valuable.)

Comment: @EliahKagan I think [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835) might be a better duplicate since windows8 OEM == UEFI while windows7 does not. This sounds like a UEFI specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

First, try [disabling Fast Startup in Windows.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) This feature is incompatible with dual-boot configurations, and it's conceivable that it's causing the problem you're seeing, although I'm far from positive of that. If this works, I'd appreciate seeing a comment to that effect so that I know it's a possible solution.

Second, if that doesn't work, you'll just have to [use the "Something Else" installation option.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-7-using-something-else) (That referenced question/answer refers to Windows 7 and may have some Windows 7-specific elements, but the basic principles still apply.) Unfortunately, a lot of people have been seeing this problem with Windows 8 and 8.1 installations, and doing the partitioning manually is what works for most people.