# Computer doesn't recognize any OS on computer

Tags: 14.04, hp, bios, mint

So I haven't seen anything like this on the forum yet... if I'm mistaken please set me straight.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Mint 17 on separate partitions of the same hard drive, along with another backup hard drive on a HP Envy Dv7. Today I restarted my computer, and the computer didn't load the GRUB, or anything. In fact it was a black screen that reads, "Please install an operating system on your computer."

Thinking that the entire computer just crashed on me, I plugged in my live usb to see what information I could salvage from the computer and all the information is still on both partitions and the secondary drive.

I reinstalled Ubuntu just to see if that would solve the issue, but it did not. I still get the same error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is a UEFI system so you may want to look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/364100/installing-xubuntu-alongside-with-uefi) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would try boot-repair tool. You can install it during Your live USB session or by creating boot-repair live CD or USB and boot from it.
You can find it there: http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ .

Comment: So I created a boot-repair tool live usb on my friends computer, but when I plugged it in and started my computer it says that the selected boot image did not authenticate. Press enter to continue... when I press enter it turns the computer off. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can try disabling 'secure boot' and enable 'legacy boot' mode in BIOS.

Comment: Alright, I figured out my problem with the boot-repair tool usb... got it to boot up in the repair tool's session, ran through the whole process and am still getting the same error. When I disabled secure boot and enabled legacy boot it brought me back to the original error screen:

Boot Device Not Found
Please install an operating system on your hard disk
Hard Disk (3F0)

Answer (score 0):

So... not sure exactly what I deleted, but I think I deleted a partition accidentally that linux needed to operate. I attached both hard drives to a different computer, formatted them both to FAT32 and reinstalled Mint through a live session. Now Mint seems to work pretty well.

Only strange part that I don't understand is why the Grub still thinks that Ubuntu 14.04 is on the system. Depending on which hard drive I boot from, it will freeze once the OS is up and running. Any thoughts?

Comment: The second paragraph is a legitimate question in its own right, I think. Unfortunately that question is off topic because questions about Linux Mint are off topic here, but you could try asking it on [Unix & Linux Q&A](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).