# Trying to dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu without having to manualy partitioning, but installer can't find windows 8

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

I'm completely new to Linux. As the title suggests, I recently decided to make the switch from Windows 8(It came installed in the laptop) to Ubuntu. I've gone through pretty much all of the steps to dual-boot Ubuntu with Windows 8. I made a bootable USB and manged to get the installer started. I didn't want to have to make my own partitions as I don't really know how to, and I don't want to mess up my laptop. the tutorial I was using said that the installer would see that I already had an OS and would give me the option to dual boot. the only thing I needed to do was set how much space I wanted Ubuntu to have.
Everything went smoothly until it came to that part. When I got to that screen, it said it couldn't find any other OS's. The only option now is to either get it to find Windows 8, or to manually partition, which I'd rather not do.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS.here's the website tutorial I followed(I double checked on other sites too):
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tired-of-windows-8-how-to-dual-boot-windows-ubuntu/
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people are reporting that the "install alongside" option doesn't work on computers that ship with Windows 8. This is probably a bug in the Ubuntu installer. I'm afraid you'll just have to use the "something else" option to partition manually. There are quite a few tutorials on the Web describing how to do this, such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-7-using-something-else) and [this one.](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/step-by-step-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-11-10.172128/)

Answer (score 0):

Go into your partition manager, and make sure that the partition you're trying to install Ubuntu on is labeled "unallocated," and not formatted.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "unallocated partition." Disk space is either unallocated or it's partitioned; it can't be both.