# Unable to install Ubuntu, during installation the 'Install alongside windows' option is missing

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I am currently trying to install Ubuntu to run beside my current Windows 7 installation. I'm installing Saucy Salamander 13.10; during installation once booted into the live CD 4 options are offered: Wipe disk, Install security (Or something of the sort), a third that escapes me, and something else.

My computer is a XPS 15 L521x
It has a Intel Core i5,
6 gigs of ram,
A 500 gigs 7200 rpm harddrive and a 32 gb cache ssd.
It has integrated and dedicated graphics (If that's relevant)

In gparted all my partitions are visible, inclusive of my three windows partitions and an additional ssd partition -There's also the 20 gigs of free storage for Ubuntu. These partitions are also available during the installation. I have tried deleting the dmraid package from terminal but to no avail.

For the Ubuntu installation I shrank my main Data partition which was initially 408 gb and after shrinking became about 390 gb. It's worth mentioning that this is my first installation of linux, and I am unfamiliar with the Linux lingo so if someone could explain in simple terms what to do I'd appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Answer (score 0):

> I shrank my main Data partition which was initially 408 gb and after shrinking became about 390 gb.

After shrinking an unallocated space was created just below 390 Gb partition.From that unallocated space create a new ext4 partition where ubuntu is going to be installed.(do all operations in gparted partition editor)

Now run the ubuntu installer and then choose something else option to install Ubuntu on the created ext4 partition.

The installer automatically asks you to create a swap partition.Give the size of the swap partition as double the RAM size(if your RAM size was low).

Answer (score 0):

I recently configured a pre-installed laptop to dual boot ubuntu 12.04 LTS along side windows. During the installation process I too didn't get the "Install Ubuntu along side windows 8 option". Therefore I chose "Something else option".

Below are few good links that might be helpful to you.

1. [Dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu-12-10 in uefi mode](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2013/03/12/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-04-in-uefi-mode/)
2. [Install Ubuntu Linux alongside windows](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html)
3. [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)
4. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18F3CZveMwg&feature=youtu.be) is a YouTube video of someone installing Ubuntu along side windows 8.
5. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LokDqte3sA4) is another YouTube video on how to install Ubuntu along side windows 8.

Good Luck