# dual boot w7 with 12.04 with gpt table and uefi

Tags: installation, dual-boot, uefi

i have a lenovo z570 with 4gb ram and 700gb hdd with w7 x64. i want to dual boot ubuntu alongside w7 but during installation, there is no install ubuntu alongside w7 option. i have tried all the methods shown in this forum and none seem to work for me. can anyone please help me out with a step by step instruction? i'm new to ubuntu and any help is appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "install alongside" option is unavailable on many EFI systems. This is probably a bug. The solution is to [use the "Something Else" option.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-7-using-something-else) (Note that the linked-to question and answer are rather BIOS-centric, but most of it still applies to EFI-based systems.)