# Installation doesn't detect Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, system-installation

My laptop came with Ubuntu. I removed it to install Windows 7 64-bit. I don't remember if I did anything special, I just formatted the entire hard drive. Now I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows, but the Ubuntu installer says:

This computer currently has no detected operating system and gives me 4 options:
 • erase disk and install Ubuntu
 • encrypt the new Ubuntu.....
 • use LVM with ......
 • something else

I tried all the solutions I could find.
ran gdisk and for //./partition0 and //./partition1 it shows:

```
mbr:mbr only    
bsd: not present    
apm: not present    
gpt: not present
```

Computer Management shows 5 partition, 4 NTFS and 1 raw 10GB space which I planned to install Ubuntu on.

c:, raw space and system reserved 100MB are primary partitions, other 2 are logical drive.

Secure boot option is disabled in BIOS and Legacy boot is selected.

Please suggest a way to get the job done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows 7 using "Something Else"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-7-using-something-else)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the option 'Something else' .you'll get the partition table.Select the partition you want to install.

[image]

Then set the filetype to ext4.Select the format checkbox.Select root  '/' as mount point.

Next before installation go to "device for boot loader installation"(see the image) and select the partition you've created just before.then press 'install now'.

---

After booting with live usb/cd ,Run following command in terminal,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

provided:  [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

I hope this will help.

Comment: Did that. The installation was completed successfully. But after rebooting when installation completed, I was straight booted in windows 7. No option to go to ubuntu.

Comment: Thansks for the help but I have a problem. I connect to internet using a usb dongle. So no internet in the boot repair program. I downloaded the boot repair iso and booted from it. On stating the tool it said without internet system would become unusable. I continued anyway but it stopped and stated I need internet connection.   Any other way to repair grub? I am gonna search it and let you know if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your:

"Did that. The installation was completed successfully. But after rebooting when installation completed, I was straight booted in windows 7. No option to go to ubuntu."

1.Download "EasyBCD" from http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/
2.Install in Windows 7
3. Add the GRUB2 for Ubuntu (google for instructions or tutorial).

Have fun with Ubuntu.