# Not Able To Install Ubuntu With Windows 7

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

First of all sorry if this question seams repeated I am a rookie, I tried many links but not able to do that is not working in my case. On my laptop currently Windows 7 is installed and I want to install Ubuntu alongside it, but I am not getting that option in my Ubuntu to [install alongside of it] menu. I tried to select "Something else" option but I don't know how to  partition it. It is my Windows 7 disk image screen shot

[image]

And this is screen shot for Ubuntu GPart

[image]

Comment: usually when installing a dual boot, i first install windows then Linux on going through two grub menus.

Comment: This explains how to make the "alongside" option appear: [How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows 7 using “Something Else”?](http://askubuntu.com/q/163962/22949)

Answer (score 0):

You already have the max of four primary partitions.  You need to backup the 4th partition (the "workspace"), and convert it to an extended partition, which may contain many logical parittions, which are fine for Ubuntu.  Tools like Partman may allow conversion in place, but I have no experience with them.  The brute force way is to delete the last primary partition (after the backup of course), recreate it as an extended, make a logical ntfs partition to restore the backup, and make additional partitions for root and swap in the remaining space.  I usually make the partitions I want before the installation, but the installation tools should allow you to partition with the "something else" option.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how many partitions you are allowed to allocate on a dynamic disk, you have *no free space* on that drive for any other partitions. Something has to go.

The first partition is a 100mb boot partition for windows. Then you've got a C: drive where your page file and system lives. Everything else is NTFS data. You can't install something alongside a completely full disk. It's not about how much space your *data* is using, your partitions are kind of reserving all the available space on the disk.

I'd remove one or more partitions in Windows itself, since the partitions are NTFS, after moving or otherwise backing up the data.