# I cannot boot into ubuntu 12.10 after installing it on windows 8

Tags: 12.10, uefi, grub-legacy

I just installed ubuntu 12.10 64bit on my hp probook 4540s windows 8 laptop, After installation I cant boot into ubuntu, the system boots directly into my windows.

Here are my installtion settings...

1. I turned off Fast Boot on Windows 8
2. I turned off Secure Boot
3. I changed from UEFI Mode to Legacy Mode(because ubuntu was not installing from a liveusb when uefi is on).
4. I created three partitions, one for swap, one for / root partition, and one for /home partition.

After installation, I installed boot-repair and run a boot-repair on the system.

After the boot-repair process, I changed back to uefi mode and it boots directly into windows.

I tried using BCD but it was only seeing the windows bootloader and no ubuntu.

Please how do I make this work..

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean 13.10? If so I recommend you edit your question. Otherwise I would try using 13.10, 12.10 was the first ubuntu to support UEFI so I imagine they have improved support a lot since then.

Comment: I meant 12.10 64bit, and also are you saying I should use 13.10 instead

Comment: Ok. Yes I think you should use 13.10.

Comment: Ubuntu supported EFI *long* before 12.10. I think you're thinking of Secure Boot support, which did indeed debut with 12.10. That said, using a more recent version is certainly in order. 12.10 is no longer supported, and EFI support has improved with every recent release.

Comment: You are right @Rod Smith, 13.10 offers better support for uefi system because I just tried installing it now and it's not throwing  any error EXCEPT that id does not detect my windows 8 OS. I had to stop to ask questions first if this is normal, if i should install the 13.10 in my ext4 partitions, will it affect my windows 8 OS? I will appreciate your help on this.. Thanks.

Comment: @Anake, yes you right 13.10 works but it does not detect any OS(my windows 8), should I go ahead with the installation or have I missed any part...

Comment: If you boot into ubuntu, get up a terminal and enter "sudo update-grub", that should detect windows and when you restart it should be there as an option

Answer (score 0):

*Do not* try to install in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode when the computer is already booting another computer in EFI/UEFI mode. You might clear an initial hurdle relatively easily this way, but you'll be setting yourself up for bigger problems down the road, as you've discovered. It's usually possible to get the installer working in EFI/UEFI mode. On rare occasion, a BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode install may be required, but this is an option of last resort.

Unfortunately, the possible causes for your initial problem are numerous, so I can't provide you with a simple procedure to overcome your problem. I do strongly recommend using a more recent version of Ubuntu, though. Also, read at least one, and preferably all three, of the following pages:

- [My page on EFI-mode Linux installations](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)
- [The Ubuntu community wiki on EFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)
- [Adam Williamson's page on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)

Comment: You are right @Rod Smith, 13.10 offers better support for uefi system because I just tried installing it now and it's not throwing  any error EXCEPT that id does not detect my windows 8 OS. I had to stop to ask questions first if this is normal, if i should install the 13.10 in my ext4 partitions, will it affect my windows 8 OS? I will appreciate your help on this.. Thanks.

Comment: First, boot into Windows and [disable Fast Startup.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) I make no promises that this will help. If it doesn't, you'll have to use the ["Something Else"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-7-using-something-else) installation option and partition the disk manually.

Comment: If i do that, will the Ubuntu detect my windows 8 OS

Comment: "Detect my Windows 8 OS" is vague. Most people mean that the installer identifies Windows and offers an option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. My hope is that disabling Fast Startup will enable this to work (among other things), but if that fails, the "Something Else" installation option works around the problem by enabling you to apply your brain to a problem that's too big for the rather stupid Ubuntu installer (namely, identifying and resizing the Windows partition). (Note I'm not dissing the Ubuntu installer; *all* computer programs are stupid, compared to the average human.)