# Ubuntu install option "Install alongside Windows 7" is missing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7

I have installed Windows 7 and now I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7.

While doing the installation, after some steps I am not getting the "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7" option in the booting process. What should I do now?

When I am watching in YouTube, it is visible as "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7" but not while am doing it.

Please tell me how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Please run Gparted from the LiveCD and post screenshot

Comment: it won't be that easy if you got uefi or gpt enabled read [this article](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) to get more view you can also find a lot of the same answers and questions within forum [search](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=how+to+dual+boot+windows+7)

Comment: See [How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows 7 using “Something Else”?](http://askubuntu.com/q/163962/22949) (which actually explains how to get the "alongside" option back.

Answer (score 2):

Boot from ubuntu live cd, do a os-prober in terminal to see if windows7 is listed.

If yes, then you are safe. Just select install alongside windows option ,then install the bootloader in the harddrive, not in any partition.

If it doesn't detect ubuntu(which is your case for now), then there is a conflict in UEFI/EFI/Legacy bootloader. Probably ubuntu is reading the UEFI BIOS, while windows 7 was installed in LEGACY bios. A Simple solution to this problem is to just turnoff the UEFI bios from bios setup & then follow step 1.

Remember if you install ubuntu evenif ubuntu doesn't detect windows7, this could  completely destroy your windows7 partition.

Enjoy & don't forget to mark my answer as accepted :)