# Install Ubuntu to a 15GB partition

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-8

I know this question is quite basic, but I am really new to linux and trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my Lenovo Y510p laptop which already have Windows 8 installed on it. What I want to do is to install Ubuntu to 15 GB partition which I made using Disk Management Utility. And I want it to dual boot to Windows/Ubuntu whenever I want.

Is this possible ? I previously installed it alongside with windows, but the problem with that was it automatically made a 250 GB partition out of one of my 600 GB partition and installed Ubuntu on that partition. I want to allocate only 15 GB to ubuntu as I will be using it for tasks like programming only, and will use Windows 8 as my primary OS. Also I don't want to install it on VM.

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard Windows disk partitioning tool to create partitions for Linux is risky at best. There are several problems with this tool, but the biggest for your scenario is that, when you create a layout that holds more than four partitions, it will convert the disk into one that uses the [Logical Disk Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) (LDM, aka "dynamic disks"). At least, that's true on MBR disks; I'm not sure if the same happens when using GPT disks, which a computer that ships with Windows 8 probably uses. LDM is a Microsoft-specific technology, and installing Linux to an LDM disk is either *very* difficult or not possible -- certainly I've never heard of anybody doing it. When people are hit by this problem, they typically end up using third-party tools to convert back from LDM to a standard configuration. There are other problems with the Windows disk partitioner, too; depending on the version, there are known bugs that can create illegal partition layouts, which of course cause their own headaches.

A better way to accomplish your goal is to use the "Something Else" installation option, as described here:

["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-7-using-something-else)

This will enable Ubuntu to do the partitioning, but under your control. This way, you won't risk a disastrous outcome should Windows decide to convert your disk to an LDM setup or otherwise mess up the partitioning.