# Ubuntu 14.04 installer won't recognize free spaces

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, windows-8, partitioning

I use disk management in windows 8 to free some spaces(50 GB). In the installing there was two options: 1-replace Ubuntu 2-Something else. I choose something else but it shows two drives but I have four drives in windows. Is there any solution that without reinstall windows I could install Ubuntu on that 50 GB .

Comment: Is it recognising your Windows?

Comment: What is the output of `lshw -class disk` and `dmesg|grep sd[a-z]`

Comment: The built-in Windows 8 Disk Management tool will give you information about how you are managing your drives in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

First, be very clear on the distinction between *hard disks* (which are physical devices) and *partitions* (which are subdivisions of disks that can be used as separate spaces). The Windows user interface doesn't always make this distinction clear, and so Windows users often refer to "disks" or "drives" when they mean partitions. My *suspicion* is that you've got one disk with four partitions. If you actually have four physical disks, please say so.

I further suspect that you've got a [Logical Disk Manager (LDM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) setup (aka *dynamic disks*). There are lots of questions about that here; for instance:

- [Partitions created in Windows are not showing in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409561/partitions-created-in-windows-are-not-showing-in-ubuntu)
- [Ubuntu Install Unknown Partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437781/ubuntu-install-unknown-partitions)
- [Install Ubuntu to a 15GB partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444455/install-ubuntu-to-a-15gb-partition)

See those questions' answers for information on converting back to a conventional setup.