# 14.04 not detecting windows 8

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, 14.04

First time I get Ubuntu to load up without having to change secure boot, UEFI but it doesn't detect my preinstalled Windows 8 on the hard drive. The option to install alongside Windows isn't available but cleaning the whole disk is always highlighted.

Comment: You probably just need to use the "Something Else" installation option, as described [here.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-7-using-something-else)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html

What is happening here is that UEFI and secureboot are new features for booting with windows 8, and Linux isn't smart enough to handle it yet.  This guide tells you step by step how to do the manual pieces for now.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: so a partition within windows is required? why isnt the option "install along windows available"

Comment: The option isn't available because the Ubuntu installer doesn't recognize a Windows 8 Secure Boot partition.  It doesn't know what it is at all, so it doesn't know it is Windows, so it doesn't provide the option.  The partition you need is on your hard drive.  What you do is to take your Windows 8 partition and Shrink it.  Then there is free space on your disc to create the Ubuntu partitions.  Typically you need create two or three.  a root "/" partition, a swap, and (optionally) a "/home/" partition to store your data in a separate drive.