# Windows 7 and Ubuntu dual boot.

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux.

I have Windows 7 on my PC. I plan on doing a dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. According to what I have read so far, by simply following the instructions on the Ubuntu prompts, the system will do the dual boot for me if I click the "install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7" option. Is this true? Does this option properly partition my hard drive to where Windows 7 AND Ubuntu will run properly?

Also, should I place the flash drive with Ubuntu installed on it in my PC BEFORE I shut my computer off and then reboot, or shut the computer off and THEN place the flash drive in the system?

Thanks for your time and answers. They are well appreciated.

Comment: Do, for sanity's sake, make a backup of your Windows 7 installation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is as simple as that.

When you install ubuntu, GRUB loader is installed as well. This loader prompts when you turn your computer on and let you choose which OS you'd like to use.

As per placing the flash drive in your PC: It doesn't matter. Just remember to change the BOOT order to USB first.

Good to know you're coming to the Linux side of the force :)

Comment: If Ubuntu is installed this way, how does the system distribute memory between Ubuntu and Windows 7?

Comment: During the installation. You can set how much memory will be distributed to the ubuntu's partion.

Comment: Perfect. Do you know if windows requires more memory than Ubuntu, or if the memory should be split in half?

Comment: It depends on the distro. I was once told that windows 7/8 needs at least 70GB space for smooth performance. Since you're installing ubuntu's version with unity and might use some other heavy window managers like gnome (they have a nice UI for people migrating from Windows), I'd suggest that you split the HD in half of leave it with at least 30GB-50GB extra in Ubuntu's partion.

Comment: How many GB's does Ubuntu need to run smoothly?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm sure that it needs less than windows, however, Unity/Gnome are heavy window managers, therefore you'll need more space. You can always revert if you're not happy with the distribution, as long as you always remember to backup important data. Hah

Comment: Just to update, I ran into some articles on installing ubuntu and other linux distros. If you're installing a minimal Linux(e.g. Arch Linux) with a 15GB partion you'll run smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to install Ubuntu is to manually install Ubuntu on a separate partition that we create for Ubuntu. See my answer in this question to how to install Ubuntu on a separate partition.
[How do I install Ubuntu 14.04 without losing data on a Windows 7 PC (physically)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490801/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-14-04-without-losing-data-on-a-windows-7-pc-physically)

You can place the flash drive before you restart or shutdown the computer. so that you can see flash drive is properly inserted in usb ports.