# avoiding grub probleme when reinstalling a new version of ubuntu

Tags: grub2

this is my first question ever in an ubuntu forum , i sused to use google , im newbie to linux i tried near 10 linux distribution and i found that the most stable is ubuntu but i hate unity cause i have to search for every thing , no categorized menu like in linux mint for example

im running ubuntu 14.4.1 , i installed grub on sda

im doing stuff on my ubuntu and saving my files to a ntfs partition , so when installing another OS or a new version of ubuntu i will only format sda1 which contain my current ubuntu installation then i will be able to use my files backed up  on the sda2 ntfs partiton in the newer ubuntu version

so next time when i install another fresh install of ubuntu will i have problem with grub cause i installed it in sda not sda1 ??

Comment: Next time you do a fresh install of Ubuntu, it will overwrite the old grub. So you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you install Ubuntu, and if you chose "Something Else" picked manual partitioning, you'll get an option to select the device for GRUB (bootloader) installation (there are pics in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/490811/158442)). If you didn't modify it (or used one of the other options instead of manual partitioning), you will likely have GRUB installed in `/dev/sda`, and if you choose to use it for GRUB the next time when you install Ubuntu, the olde GRUB will be overwritten. So you should be safe.

Comment: thanks ,i installed GRUB in sda , if i choose to install windows in the partition where i have ubuntu now , will i face problems with GRUB on boot ?

Comment: Windows usually overwrites GRUB if installed on the hard drive (like you did), so no, you shouldn't face problems.

Comment: waw askubuntu is the fastest forum i ever used ! thanks a lot :)