# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 to dual boot with windows 7 on one hard drive

Tags: dual-boot

I'm a linux newbie, I'm trying to install ubuntu 14.04 together with my current windows 7 setup. So I burned a DVD with the .iso file and booted into it, started the install process and from what I see from the internet there should be an option to "Install alongside...", but I don't have that because appearently it doesn't recognize my windows install (I have one 500GB hard drive with 100GB free - all in one partition). So from what I saw I need to use fixparts to fix device `sda` which is my hard drive. But it warns me that it doesn't start from sector 1 and it can cause problems in certain OSs. I don't want to confirm it because I'm afraid it might corrupt my hard drive, is it safe?

Before I thought about writing this question I tried partitioning manually via the "Something else" option. But in all the guides I saw, they have "free space" as an option, while I have one partition that is 500GB with 400GB used, maybe I could change the size of my partition to 400GB and then I'll have free space, but then I have no space in windows 7, should I change the size to 420GB and the rest 80GB assign to linux partitions as the guide says?

I would really appreciate it if you answer both my questions, or if you think answering one question will eliminate the need for the other, I'd appreciate that too.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this question: ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used the automated partitioning tool as you mention in your first question. To that end, I'll say that it is not safe or at least not as safe as manually partitioning it.

If your hard drive only has 100GB of its 500GB free then yes, you should partition it to leave at least 30GB if not 50GB or more for Ubuntu. I have run Ubuntu with zero space problems with a 30GB partition. You should boot into Windows and using the Windows partitioning tool shrink your Windows partition to 400-something GB, leaving free space available for your Ubuntu installation.

Comment: I saw in a guide I needed to do that, but doesn't that leave my windows partition with no space left?

Comment: @shoham - no, because if it has 100Gb free in window, and shrink it by 30Gb, you will end up with 70Gb... Note 400-*something*, sort of meaning 400+

Comment: @Wilf Can't this cause data loss?

Comment: @Tim Logically I would think windows will remove the free space part.

Comment: But it can cause data loss editing the partitions on a harddrive can't it?

Comment: I have shrunk my Windows partition within Windows many times and never had a data loss problem. Windows should be smart enough to only shrink the actual free space portion.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to ask what happens if I want to add more space to ubuntu. Do I delete stuff from my windows partition, shrink it, then what? Do I have to reinstall?

Comment: If you need more space on Ubuntu: 1. Boot into Windows and shrink the Windows partition the amount of space you want for Ubuntu. 2. Boot into a live-USB or live-DVD of Ubuntu. 3. Install GParted 4. Expand your Ubuntu partition to encompass the new free space available. [How-To-Guide with Pictures](http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/)

Comment: @Tim - if it was full, it might. Most partition editors aren't stupid enough to remove used space. It should remove free space out of the partition (if there is 100Gb free, removing 30/50Gb of that free space shouldn't hurt), making it available for the partition where Ubuntu can go.

Comment: @Wilf okay then, I just had some memory - evidently a wrong memory!

Answer (score 0):

You have 100GB free on the windows partition. What you need to do is boot from the Ubuntu DVD you made and run a program named GParted. inside that program you can resize your windows partition leaving empty, unallocated space. Then you can launch he installer and do the 'install alongside' option and it'll see the free unallocated space and allow you to install there.  --- Have Fun!!