# Ubuntu doesn't detect my Windows partition

Tags: system-installation

I have a windows machine with which I want to explore ubuntu. I downloaded and put it on a disk OK. I fixed my boot order and booted into ubuntu. Right there on the screen it asked me if I wanted to install ubuntu. I was feeling optimistic and said yes. Then I got to the part where it wants to know where to put it, but it informed me that there was no other OS on my HD! It wanted to wipe the drive. I got out of there quick and booted back into Windows, just to make sure. Why is it not seeing 9 GBs of Windows and associated programs?

Additionally, is this going to make a partition on my HD? I hope so!

Comment: See step 9, and in particular the link that it offers, for more info as to how to properly partition your discs for install.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Duplicate to: [“Install alongside” option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using “Something Else”?](http://askubuntu.com/q/163962/40581), the link to the install instructions is also very good.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Ubuntu on your machine then you've got to have somewhere to put it - i.e. a separate partition on your Windows hard disk or a second (blank) hard drive.  If all you have is one drive with Windows on it and you try to install Ubuntu then it is probably is going to assume you want to wipe Windows and replace it with Ubuntu!

What sort of system/setup do you have? How many hard drives, etc.?