# dual booting ubuntu 14.04 with windows 7 ultimate

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation

6 months ago I formatted my 320GB hard disk drive and changed the partition table to GPT, then I installed windows 8.1. With gparted I formated my whole hard disk and changed the partition table to MSDOS. Then I installed windows 7 ultimate.

After that I started to install ubuntu 14.04 but there was no option to install along side my windows 7. I didn't pay attention and I selected something else. I made 30 GB partition for Ubuntu and 3 GB for swap with gparted. All the things went well but when I started the lap top again it was only Uuntu booting and there wasn't any option to choose windows booting. It seemed that windows is not installed.

Then I again formated my HDD and installed windows 7. Now I want to install ubuntu but still facing the same problem. There is no option to install along side windows 7. Ubuntu doesn't recogniz my os. I tried `sudo os-prober` but it answers nothing.

What should I do ?
I do really love ubuntu?
Sorry for my bad english.
With special thanks.

Comment: Try: 1) Installing Linux and setting up all partitions (including one with NTFS, or empty, for Windows. 2) Install Windows in the empty space/NTFS partition. 3) Only Windows will boot, because Windows does not recognize Linux (but it's there). 4) You now have two options, use "EasyBCD" to add Linux to the Windows boot screen, or boot from a live usb stick and install GRUB (which will recognize both Windows and Linux fine).

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Comment: But I already installed windows. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

It is best, IMO, to install the Windows OS first, in its NTFS partition as you have done. Then install Ubuntu. When you get to the Replace/Alongside/Something Else choices for partitioning, click the Something Else option. This gets you to a partition editor like gparted or similar. Use that to choose or create partitions for Linux swap (maybe about 12 Gig) and for Ubuntu itself (maybe 50 Gig, or more if you think you will need). You can use file system type EXT4 for the Ubuntu partition. The Linux swap partition has its own file system type: linux swap. When your partitions seem satisfactory, continue the installation. (Sorry that the installation instructions are unclear at that point for someone not accustomed to partitioning.)