# Windows 8.1 OS not detected when installing Ubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.0.4 alongside Windows 8.1, but I do not get that as an option when installing. Instead I get a message saying that there is no current OS detected.

I have gone through many help guides and have tried everything from disabling fast boot and secure boot to creating an UEFI bootable USB drive.

Step by step solutions would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)