# Ubuntu inside/alongside windows 7 not taking my deleted partition(After selecting install ubuntu inside windows, my system restarts back)

Tags: dual-boot

My computer model is 
Dell studio 1555, with 4GB Ram and Intel core 2 DUO processor(500 GB HDD).
Previously(probably 2012/13), the system was successfully installing any versions properly alongside WINDOWS 7. Unfortunately, I lost those DVDs. Now I have downloaded Ubuntu(12.04.2, 12.04.5[both/32 and 64 bit], 14.10[64 bit]) neither of them, getting installed(I deleted a drive of 80 GB approx. like I previously used to install Ubuntu). Instead, whenever I try to install, it goes well up to the page where "Install inside windows 7..." appears. After that I click to continue installing. But surprisingly, DVD gets ejected.

And more surprisingly, earlier when I installed it, i got an option -
"Install Alongside Windows 7"
But now a days, it says - 
"Install Inside Windows 7"

Now a days, i am using External DVD drive(Installs Windows 7 properly).

And I tried to install thorough WUBI command prompt too. But some error messages generated. Dear friends, please help me to tackle this.

Comment: Install inside Windows or Wubi is not supported anymore.  You have to reboot and in BIOS select to boot from USB or DVD drive. You cannot start Ubuntu install if booted in WIndows.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using

Comment: @Eliah Kagan The ISO is written into DVD. Tried to install even by writing into a USB too. But now trying that by DVDs. it starts the process whenever i insert the dvd and restart goes everything well until reaches "Install ubuntu inside windows 7....." but after that, when I click on the option continue to install, It ejects the DVD and asks to remove the dvd and press enter. Once i do that, it restarts the system. as Windows 7 only. No boot dual boot. nothing to install there. Idont know what to do. previously i installed the system in this way. It was installed properly without any problem.

Comment: @EliahKagan, I have chosen boot from the DVD ROM. But I am using External DVD Drive connected through USB. Is this a problem ??

Comment: @EliahKagan bro, what is the difference between these two option ? "Install Alongside Windows 7" And "Install inside Windows 7" ? Is this the point where I am struck  at ?

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information @EliahKagan bro. Now, how can I solve the problem ? I tried all the possible means i know. I went to to choose even "Something Else" option. There also, tried to use the free space, as one youtube video tutorial shows me. But i could only make one 330 mb primary memory there. after that the remaining space says "Unsusable". Brother, starting to feel frustration. probably ubuntu is not my cup of tea !!!

Comment: @Khalid If no option to install *alongside* Windows is shown on the same screen that gives you the option to do *something else*, then as [oldfred suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607868/ubuntu-inside-alongside-windows-7-not-taking-my-deleted-partitionafter-selectin?noredirect=1#comment851566_607868) I suggest trying the techniques at [“Install alongside” option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using “Something Else”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/163962/22949) Specifically, [you should be able to get the *alongside* option back](https://askubuntu.com/a/163974/22949).

Comment: is the hard disk damaged partially or fully ?? Is that the reason brother ?

Comment: Previously in 2012 or earlier 2013, to install ubuntu, what i did is, deleted a partition using Disk Management in windows 7. And Ubuntu took that deleted partition automatically. And let me to install the OS alongside the windows. that went everthing like oldfred suggestion. But this time too i tried to install exactly the same way....dont know what happened !!!

Answer (score -1):

You need to install Windows prior to installing Ubuntu.  Windows uses MBR (Master Boot Record), and Linux uses Grub as the OS loader.  Linux is flexible, and will install with Windows alongside it, but if you try to install Windows after having installed Ubuntu, you're out of luck.  Well, not entirely, but there's a lot of mucking around to do.

Just make sure you have enough space.  I wouldn't recommend installing Windows 7 on any partition less than 100GB, from my experience.  Because, you want to allow for updates, and whatever software you use, such as games and other stuff.  I've installed Win7 on 80GB partitions, and after installing a couple of games, I started running out of space.  You don't want to get too close to your partition's end, because that's when you start to experience lag on your OS.  Although Win7 does a better job than FAT32 at keeping your filesystem neat and defragged, you'll still run into trouble when trying to find swap space.  So do yourself a favor ... Take any backups that you can, and start over.  If you can afford to, get another hard drive.

Once you've backed up, boot from your Windows DVD.  Format the hard drive, and create one partition for Windows, and the rest of the drive, leave it blank.  This way, when you decide to install Ubuntu, it too can create it's own partition.  I'd recommend at least 80GB for Ubuntu ... but take that figure with a grain of salt.  I use a bunch of stuff, so I need the space.  Realistically, you can run Ubuntu with 8GB and be OK, but that's keeping all your other software elsewhere.  Perhaps a NAS or Samba share.

If you need further detail on how to do this, follow [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).

Best of luck!  Just remember, the figures I gave above are to be taken with caution.  If you know you don't need that much, then go ahead and by all means make them smaller.  If you need to keep those larger, feel free to make them larger, as I don't know how you'll use your's.  I like to estimate and allow for expansion, but if you know how much space your final set-up will take up, then use your discretion.