# Installing Ubuntu in dual boot mode with Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: system-installation

I have a bootable usb for Ubuntu 14.04 when I go for installing Ubuntu I don't get to see "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" option, however Windows 7 Ultimate is already installed on my machine. How do I make my machine dual boot for windows 7 and ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Comment: here is a complete walkthrough for windows-dual-booting for nearly any problem you maybe face: http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/354350

Answer (score 0):

Often, Ubuntu installer cannot identify Windows in the HD. Even if it does, it is better to select "Do something else" and create a partition manually and install Ubuntu. I'm saying this because once I tried the "install alongside" option and the result was that the whole HD was formatted and Ubuntu got installed on it.