# Building partition between Linux and Windows

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I can't build a partition. If I want to run Linux(Ubuntu) along with Windows 10 in my laptop, can I put the Linux in a different drive?

I don't want to use Ubuntu through USB drive. I want to install it in one of my hard drives,preferably D drive. What should I do? How can I perform this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'I can't build a partition.'?

Answer (score 0):

When you install the installer may offer to install alongside automatically, otherwise you can chose the 'Something Else' option and install manually. You will probably need to shrink the partition in Windows, and then install alongside. Make sure you make a backup of important data first.

It may help to read the following questions:

- [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)
- ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install Ubuntu on your "D" drive.  I ran that way since February.

First download 14.04 and install it on a USB drive instead of a DVD.

What I did was remove the Windows HDD and then install Ubuntu with only the Ubuntu drive in the computer.

Then I added the Windows drive back.  I had to set the BIOS to do the dual booting for me.  Leave the BIOS in EUFI secure mode when you install Ubuntu.

The trick is when you leave Windows to boot to Ubuntu.  You'll need to do a complete shut-down.  The shut-down in Windows normally is just a hybrid of hibernate and sleep.  You'll need to hold the shift key down while clicking the shut-down option in the menu.

Since I mostly used Ubuntu, I set the BIOS to boot to the Ubuntu drive as the primary.

When I was ready to boot Windows, when the computer gave me the option of going to the BIOS or boot menu, I pressed F-10 and it gave me a choice of windows or ubuntu.  I chose windows and operated.  When leaving Windows, I had to do a full shutdown or start a reboot in order to get the boot option menu again.

Answer (score 0):

Linux does not recognize drives as 'drive C:' or 'drive D:'. Rather, the primary hard-drive (probably drive c) is known as /dev/sda, and the secondary drive (probably drive d) is /dev/sdb. So, your windows installation, according to Linux, would probably be on /dev/sda1. 

Assuming that drive D is completely empty, you can choose 'Something Else' during the installation, and select '/dev/sdb
' (assuming thats you D drive). Just make sure to set it to format to ext4 and set the mount point as /. 

If you cannot figure out which drive is which, open up gparted on your live cd, and it should tell you.

Good luck, and hope this helps!