# Help with Ubuntu Installation (14.04.3 LTS)

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I use a HP Pavilion dv6 laptop that runs on Windows 7. I'm unable to install Ubuntu 14.4.3 into the PC. I have created a flash drive (thumb drive) with Ubuntu on it using the tool in pendrivelinux.com/
First of all, I don't see the welcome screen that should look like this at all:

[image]

I see a black and white screen with the logo of Ubuntu and a bunch of options one below the other and I have no idea why. I can try Ubuntu using the flash drive. When I attempt to install it, it simply doesn't let me.

When I reach the step where I must select the installation type, I can't select the 1st option,which is "Install Ubuntu Inside Windows 7" it simply restarts the PC and nothing happens. I can't select the 2nd option, that is "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" since I need Windows and it allows me to proceed with the 3rd option, that is 'Something Else'

After I continue, I see a page where I must select the device for boot loader.

If I try to make a new partition table ( using /dev/sda ) , it tells me that it will delete all other partitions so I can't do that. And obviously I can't install the Ubuntu loader on the Windows loader or recovery stuff.  And I can't install it on unallocated space that I freed by shrinking Local Disk (C:) because it tells me that it is unusable. I can't install it on /dev/sda itself because it tells me that there is no root file defined.
Can someone please me kind enough to help me proceed with the installation process. I've tried finding the answers on the net, but all of them are either too complicated or useless.
I'm really sorry about the lack of pictures. I'm a new user so the site is restricting me from doing so.

**Update:**

After selecting the "Something else" option, this is the data that appears:

/dev/sda

/dev/sda1  ntfs Size: 208 MB Used: 30 MB (Windows 7 loader)

/dev/sda2  ntfs Size: 984134 MB Used: 55228 MB (Windows Recovery Environment loader)

/dev/sda3  ntfs Size: 15750 MB Used:13808 MB (Windows Recovery Environment loader)

**Update 2**

I made a bootable USB drive using the "Startup Disk Creator" present in Ubuntu. I can now see the welcome screen properly. I still cannot install Ubuntu using "Install Ubuntu in Windows 7" as it still restarts when I pick that option. I still need help from you on how to install Ubuntu using "Something else" option. Please note that for me, it is displaying as "Install *In* Windows 7" rather than displaying it as "Install Ubuntu *Alongside* Windows 7"

Comment: Use Windows to shrink Windows NTFS partition and make unallocated space for Ubuntu. Reboot immediately into Windows so it can run chkdsk which is always required after a resize. Make sure not hibernated. If you are getting any install inside Windows that is the obsolete wubi installer. So not use that, but boot flash drive installer from BIOS, not wubi from inside Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Answer (score 0):

The 1st option didn't work for you, and I think that might be because of the installation media's fault. Anyway, I'll go on to the 3rd option.

First you will need to have free space. So shrink some hard disk and leave about 12 or 15 GB at least. You can achieve that with windows built-in **Disk Management Utility** which can be called by typing `diskmgmt.msc` in run box. And proceed to shrink the hard disk.

1. Creating Swap space. After you have some free space, click on `Free Space` And click on the <kbd>+</kbd> sign which will be on bottom left corner (if there is no <kbd>+</kbd> sign, then there'll probably be `Add` Button. And swap space should be about the size of your RAM, if your RAM is 8 GB, 4 GB of swap should be enough. And choose paritition type as `Swap Space`
2. Creating root partition. This is the partition where the OS will be
   installed. Create a new partition, as for type, use either *ext3* or
   *ext4*. And in the mount location, choose `/`.
3. Creating home partition. This is optional step. But it's a good idea
   to have another partition for home directory, in case something
   wrong with your ubuntu os and you can chill, knowing you saved your
   4000 words essay inside home directory. If you want to do it then create another partition, use ext3 or ext4 and choose mount point as `/home`

And that's basically it. You can continue installation. You might have to select the `/` partition though.

Btw, it would help if you can provide the screenshots or images in your question.