# Ubuntu 14.04 installation: Ubuntu installer didn't detect windows 10

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

I used this thread to install ubuntu : [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) . But after booting from Live USB , ubuntu isn't able to locate windows during installation. I have dynamic disk partitions inwhich windows is installed. So, is there any workaround for installing ubuntu without converting my old partitions from dynamic to basic?

Thank you.
P.S.Let me know if anything else is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic disk is a windows only feature. see this on how to install Ubuntu: ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Answer (score 0):

Same for me, but when I installed the New Ubuntu 15.10 it Now detects my Windows 10 as "Windows 10 Loader" and when i click it loads windows 10 with no problem.

With a FREE Ubuntu 15.10 DVD, you can add a Ubuntu partition or just wipe the partition which Ubuntu is installed in and remember to mount to / so it will install.

Comment: Your answer doesn't actually solve the OP's problem. Yes, it should work, but there is a reason why it doesn't.

Comment: @Carlm3 , I prefer to install LTS version.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)