# Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 with legacy bios?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

Ubuntu won't detect windows 10 when I try to install it, so I'm assuming it is because my BIOS is not in UEFI mode, but rather, in Legacy mode. Is there any way for me to still be able to install ubuntu alongside my windows installation?

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are u referring to? Ubuntu gives you the possibility to install it in legacy mode as well.  Have you allocated space on the disk for Ubuntu? Take a look here:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2236762

Comment: @orestis Not sure right now but it's either 14.04 or 15.10. No I haven't but I shall do that now. The thread starts getting a bit technical so I'm not too sure what they are doing there. But my guess is that I will have to install ubuntu onto the unpartitioned space and then maybe do something else to make it have a boot option? I really don't know

Comment: windows 10 only works in uefi mode (i think), so you probably need to reinstall ubuntu in UEFI mode, disable Secure-boot in bios and fast-boot on windows first, at least i did that with windows 8 and it worked

Comment: @philsegeler right so I'll disable secure boot in the bios, and is fast boot a windows option or a bios option? Also why does my System Information say that the Bios is on Legacy mode? This must mean that Windows 10 works on Legacy too?

Comment: by default windows works in uefi mode, you need to reset the bios to uefi mode, go to windows to disable fast startup http://superuser.com/questions/957081/how-to-enable-disable-fast-startup-in-windows-10 then reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode

Comment: If I set the bios to uefi mode, will it still recognise my windows then? and I've turned fast boot off now. I'll go into the bios ASAP and let you know further

Comment: yes ubuntu should recognize windows in uefi mode! now after you disable secureboot install Ubuntu in UEFI mode normally. Sadly, it's 1:30 in the morning where i leave and i wont reply for 10 hours+.

Comment: @philsegeler well, thank you for your help, I'll see what I can do, and how would I select specifically to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode, or is this done automatically?

Comment: If you upgraded a Win 7 to Win8 - 10 then you could be running in legacy mode.  Both Windows and Ubuntu must be in the same mode for ease of use.

Comment: @Dominik H it is done automatically, now have a good day/night!

Comment: I had Windows 7 in the past, upgraded to windows 10, then formatted and installed ubuntu, then formatted and installed windows 10 from fresh again, and now I'm trying to run ubuntu alongside of Windows 10, so it could mean that it might still be on Legacy mode because of my initial windows 7 on the pc? 

@philsegeler I see, thank you! And you too!

Comment: It appears that I have no secure boot option in my bios. Now what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/163962) It appears your machine has Windows 10 installed in BIOS (not UEFI) mode. This is possible if the machine shipped without Windows or with Windows 7 or earlier, and was either set in that mode or doesn't have UEFI at all. Even if you can switch to UEFI you probably shouldn't: you'd have to reinstall Windows. If you can boot the Windows system and the Ubuntu live USB without doing anything special, the live system should be in the same mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I am a new 'Ubuntuan' (permit me to use that word) too!

This is my first answer on the forum, I hope to give it a good try.

From what you said, i presume you have a working windows 10 OS!

Download the Ubuntu ISO image from the Ubuntu website [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Download [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie) to setup a USB drive to be used as boot manager.

Open rufus after download
Select the drive you want to install on.
Select the partition scheme for both legacy and UEFI modes
Leave file system and cluster size as default
In the `Create bootable disk using` option, select ISO Image, then click the icon beside to pick the Ubuntu ISO Image you downloaded.
Then click `start` to start the operation.

You should know when the process is done.

However, due to Windows Fast Boot options, your computer might boot directly into Windows 10 without booting from the Ubuntu Boot manager you created (Which i assume is connected to your system). You can force your system to load your external drives by Reordering the Boot Options in your BIOS setup. And some computers will give you access to select which drive to boot from when you press a specific key (mostly F12 or ESC key) immediately your computer powers on.

Then select the USB Bootable manager you created, and UBUNTU should load then.
Follow the download process to install Ubuntu and enjoy freedom for life!
Thanks.

Comment: for legacy should use universal usb installer instead of rufus.

Answer (score 0):

## Correction

@philsegeler 's comment in the question is not true.

Windows 10 supports both UEFI and Legacy mode. You need to check your Windows installation BIOS mode following this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/946868/how-to-test-whether-windows-10-was-installed-with-uefi).

## Answer

You need to boot Ubuntu image from Generic Flash Disk (**NOT** UEFI: Generic Flash Disk) in BIOS boot option to install alongside with Windows in Legacy mode.

According to the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#SecureBoot), the Secure Boot is only available in UEFI. If you have Windows in Legacy mode, I think you don't need to turn that off in your BIOS setting. As you could see the "Secure Boot State" in System Information Utility will be "Unsupported".

Comment: If I use a Ubuntu Installation usb, I should find 'Generic flash disk' from BIOS menu ? I installed Ubuntu in UEFI and windows is in BIOS, now I can't boot to any... Is there a way to boot back to windows?