# How to install Ubuntu "alongside windows"?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I'm currently using windows 10 and want to install ubuntu as dual boot.But I can not get the "alongside windows" option when I'm trying to install ubuntu.Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you resize Windows partition from Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Answer (score 0):

You might see option '**Something else**'
select it.

now select partition where you want to install **ubuntu**
asign '**/**' partition  and **swap** partition.

[image: Screenshot while installing Xubuntu]

**NOTE:-** select partition carefully,take important data backups in case you fail.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Disk Management** in Windows and select your **C:** by clicking it. Right click on the selected disk and select **Shrink volume...**. Reduce your disk size and click **Shrink**.

Power off the PC and restart entering the BIOS/UEFI. Select your installation drive to boot first, save and reboot.

Now you should have the option **Install Ubuntu alogside Windows**.

If you still don't get that option select Something else and do partitioning by yourself.

Create a SWAP partition like your RAM (if you have more than 8GB of RAM 4-8GB SWAP should be enough).

Create an EXT4 partition with the remaining space assigning that **/** as mount point.

Ubuntu should use Windows EFI partition to install the GRUB.

Now you should be able to compleet the installation.

When installation process has completed, remember to disable Windows fast startup from Power options or Ubuntu will never boot.