# Can't see "Install alongside Windows" option

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I am new to Ubuntu and very confused. I have installed  Ubuntu 14.04.3 onto a USB flashdrive and tried it from that. I must say I like what I saw BUT I have a few initial questions. First is that when I run install (to install it on my laptop, a Spanish Compaq CQ57) where I expect to see a window giving me a choice of 'Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7', 'Replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu'  or 'Something else' there is a different window which doesn't have the 'Install alongside' option. Which option in this window should I select if I want to install alongside Windows 7? And then what do I do?

Secondly, the keyboard on my laptop doesn't have a number pad and it seems as though none of the numerous configurations available are compatible with my machine. I have seen lots of advice on forums but most seem to be beyond the scope of a non-techie, wary novice like me.

I would really like to move away from Windows (I have tried and don't like Windows 10, although I have quite happily used 7 for several years) but I am beginning to wonder if Ubuntu is beyond me and if I should give up and stick to Windows.

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: Regarding the keyboard: please create 1 question per topic. I would assume the best thing to do is to find out the name of the keyboard in your current OS and see you can find the same one in Linux. Or the closest one.

Comment: If you don't see "Install alongside Windows" you can manually partiion your disk to put Ubuntu side-by-side with Windows. Select "Something else", make the desired partition, select to format it as ext4 and set its mountpoint as `/`. Make sure Windows' partition is safe and proceed to installation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Answer (score 1):

You only get to see the "install alongside" if there is place to create a system alongside what is currently there. So ... use your favorite partitioning tool to create "unallocated space" (for Ubuntu 25Gb or more) and it will show up.