# No root file system is defined , what should I do?

Tags: system-installation, wubi

When I try to install Ubuntu in Windows 10 using `wubi.exe`, when I boot, I get an error says `No root file system is defined` and the installation is not complete.

Please help.

Comment: Sorry wubi is not supported

Comment: The official Wubi versions do not work. So avoid it or try a [community supported version](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases)

Answer (score 1):

Wubi isn't being developed anymore. If you just want to try Ubuntu you can use a LiveUSB without modifying your current install, or a virtual machine with something like VirtualBox.

Comment: okay , another question when I try to dual boot and install ubuntu alongside windows , I check on try something else but my hard drive appears as one partition , so what should I do to install it alongside windows 10 ( without wubi )

Comment: @MohamedAmin if you have another question, please start another question (after some investigation hasn't brought a useful answer)... - but i think you are looking for something like https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi or https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Wubi "No root file system is defined" means that linux drivers cannot use your file **/ubuntu/disks/root.disk**.

Wubi.exe creates an empty file **/ubuntu/disks/root.disk** on Windows with Windows drivers and a setup file for [Ubiquity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity).

After first reboot [Ubiquity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity) should process the setup file automatically and should use the file **/ubuntu/disks/root.disk**. But [Ubiquity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity) runs native with linux drivers of course. Sometimes [Ubiquity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity) cannot use your file because there are linux issues with your disks/partitions.

So, what can you do? If you want Wubi, you can try a release 303 or above from [here](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases) (e.g.wubi1510r303). r303 has a fix for parted 3.2 and bugs of parted can cause your issue.

If you don't want Wubi, see tips of the other users.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the first comment, Wubi *is* still supported, but

- Only on BIOS systems (no UEFI)
- Only on Windows XP, Vista and 7.

Even if you can still enable a legacy BIOS mode, WUBI doesn't work with Windows 10's bootloader.

You'll have to do a proper install (eg dual boot) or use a virtual machine.

Comment: okay , another question when I try to dual boot and install ubuntu alongside windows , I check on try something else but my hard drive appears as one partition , so what should I do to install it alongside windows 10 ( without wubi )

Comment: The installer should offer to resize the Windows partition. It can do this safely. If it doesn't offer that (ie it doesn't understand that it's a Windows partition) don't continue and make sure you have shut Windows down correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The "No root file system is defined" shows up when you forget to pick a partition and name it "/". That is a mandatory name for the root system on Linux/Ubuntu.

As stated by others: windows 10 is not a supported OS for a WUBI install. Microsoft changed its boot with W8 and newer versions that made it dangerous to use WUBI (loss of data is the worst thing that can happen).