# No installation type menu

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation

I finally went to make the switch from Windows to Ubuntu. That's all great, but I have been trying to install it for 5 days now.

I made a bootable Ubuntu 16.04.3 USB drive plugged it into my computer, and booted it up. I then tried to go through the installation wizard, now, in every tutorial I have looked at has said the exact same thing "You go through the first couple steps then it will ask you to pick an option: Replace Windows with Ubuntu, Install Ubuntu alongside Windows, or Something else".

Sadly I don't get that menu, instead it takes me straight to a partitioning menu. Even that doesn't work,  if I try to make a new partition the install wizard freezes and crashes.

Here is a picture of the blank installation type menu,

[Blank Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk3Sc.png)

Comment: It appears the installer is not seeing your Windows partitions. There are other questions on this site about that, I can't show you links, I am using a low-rent device.

Comment: Now on a real PC, here's a good one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using

Answer (score 0):

So here's how I got it to install,

In the BIOS raid was on, I turn it to AHCI mode, then I booted up and boom it worked.

It asked me if I wanted to turn on Legacy boot mode I said yes, and it installed.