# Screen Freezes On Installation Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: system-installation, screen, freeze

I'm getting to a screen in the installer that says "Installation Type." There's a little table below that's empty and a dropdown menu that says "Device for boot loader information" with only one option (/dev/sda). It won't let me continue with the installation without doing something on this screen, but as soon as I hit any buttons it freezes up.

Can anyone help with this? I'm not an expert by any means and just want to get this installation set up so I can do other things.

Comment: You don't need to be an expert but you do need to know some basic stuff. Namely, BIOS or UEFI? Better [edit] the question and post hardware specifications, so we can start with something.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: I followed the procedure used here and it worked perfectly. [No installation type menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966235/no-installation-type-menu).

> In the BIOS RAID was on. I turn it to AHCI mode, then I booted up and it worked. It asked me if I wanted to turn on Legacy boot mode. I said yes, and it installed.