# No Option to Install Alongside Windows

Tags: dual-boot, 17.10

I do not see the option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows in the installer.

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your windows is not genuine. No problem if you have a unallocated space in your hard disk you can dual boot your system by selecting

> something else  >  (continue)  >  free space  >  (+)  >  use as  >  Swap Area   >  (enter the size) (max it should be the size of your RAM or 2x of your RAM) (don't change any thing apart from these)  >  (OK)  >  free space  >  (+)  >  mount > select ->( / ) (first option) (apart from this don't change any thing if you want you can change the size of disk)  >  (OK) >  (select newly created partition)  >  (install now).

hope this will work for you.

Thank you.