# Ubuntu 18.04.1 & Windows 10 dual boot installation issue

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 18.04

I’m running into an issue when installing the latest version of Ubuntu on my Windows 10 computer for a dual boot configuration. When I get to the ‘Installation type’ screen I’m not getting the option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. I only get the ‘Erase disk and install Ubuntu’ option. I’ve already shrunk C: drive (30GB) to free up space for Ubuntu. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `Something else` instead and choose the drive in which you want to install.

Comment: select `something else` and install on your free space option sir.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Answer (score 1):

You normally have something like "Something else" where you can install Ubuntu on a specific partition.

[image]

**If it's not the case can you take a screenshot ?**

I hope that will help you!