# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 doesn't find the Windows version

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

For university I require to install Ubuntu 16.04 as dual boot next to my windows install.

I am not getting the option install Ubuntu next to my Windows install, as it did not detect any previous installs.

I've checked ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using) and I can conclude:

- My laptop uses UEFI, secure boot is disabled
- My laptop was correctly shut down
- Hybernating is disabled
- Fast startup is disabled
- The Windows partition is not damaged
- It is not a Windows Dynamic Disk
- The Windows partition has been shrunk (I got 30GB of unused space where I want the Ubuntu install to be located, on my SSD).

As many other threads I've found, I can only choose between installing ubuntu as only boot, or choose something else, where I can only find my HDD and not my SSD. I think this is the reason why the installer didn't find the Windows install, as it did only check the HDD?

Any suggestions what to try next? Is there any way to get the option install alongside windows 10?