# Not given the ‘install alongside windows 10’ option. Looked at other threads but they didn’t help also

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, live-usb

I have a windows 10 DELL XPS 15 7590. The steps that I have taken to dual boots are:

1. Download UBUNTU 18.04
2. Set up a live USB using etcher.io
3. Create an unallocated partition to install Ubuntu
4. Boot in to USB and install Ubuntu

However during this step. I’m not presented with the option to install alongside Windows 10. The only drive it shows is my USB and that doesn’t work. I don't even get the option to replace windows with Ubuntu. Please could someone help me I’ve been stuck for a long time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Comment: In addition to link above, Dell typically needs UEFI update and SSD firmware update. And you have to change drive in UEFI settings from Intel RST to AHCI. But if still booting Windows you must first install the Windows  AHCI drivers.