# Install alongside Windows 10 option is not appearing, Windows boot drive seems to be unrecognized

Tags: system-installation, windows-10, usb-installation

I was trying to install Ubuntu in a dual boot with Windows 10. I tried Ubuntu 20.04 (which had issues with Intel RST and couldn't be fixed, so ignore this version), Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 16.04. While installing, the *Install alongside Windows 10* option is not showing up.

[image: Screenshot]

It seems that my boot drive is not recognized. I have a 512GB SSD and a 1TB HDD. Windows is installed on the SSD and I shrank it to make free space of 100GB. If I click the *Something Else* option only the HDD is shown during installation.

[image: Screenshot]

I've deactivated secure boot and fast startup. And I boot the USB from UEFI, so it should be the same as windows.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Comment: Instead of 'Install Alongside', use 'Something Else'

Comment: The problem is I can't see my SSD during installation, where I want to install it. So use "something else" I could only install it on my HDD.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it, the problem was the SATA setting. It was set to RAID / RST, but Ubuntu needs AHCI to find the SSD. Followed this tutorial [here](https://samnicholls.net/2016/01/14/how-to-switch-sata-raid-to-ahci-windows-10-xps-13/), but be careful, it may make your computer unable to boot. In my case (Dell G5) it worked but I needed to follow the comments and boot into safe mode to properly boot.