# No option to install Ubuntu along side Windows

Tags: dual-boot

I have a windows 10 professional 64 bit OS on a PC I've recently built. I want to install Ubuntu along side it so I can boot into Windows for games, Ubuntu for everything else.

I have a 1 TB M2 SSD that Windows is installed on that I want to split between the two OS's. When I try and install Ubuntu - I don't get an option to install along side windows and the partition screen confuses me.

Can you help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“Install alongside” option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using “Something Else”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/163962/) and [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Answer (score 0):

You only get the options that are valid for your setup.

If you do not have an unallocated partition there is no "install alongside" possible so it is not shown. Create an unallocated partition from windows if you want to use that option.

If you have a partition formatted as NTFS you can use the "something else" option and mark that partition. Be careful: the installer will remove any data on it so if you pick c: or another partition that holds personal data... it is gone.

Before anything else: make a backup.