# is "erase disk and install ubuntu" reversible

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, windows

Say I wanted to factory reset my computer would I still have access to windows 10 or would this command completely delete windows 10 from my computer?

Comment: The title is on topic but the body is not and is not what the title ask. The title: no. The body: depends on what a factory reset does and how your system is setup.  Seems off topic to me.

Comment: @Rinzwind Well, erase disk and restore backups should do it ;^)  Up to the vendor what "factory restore" does, so off-topic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's vendor specific, not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: "Say I wanted to factory reset my computer" Once you **erase disk and install Ubuntu** there is no option to **factory reset**. There is no Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

"*Erase disk and install Ubuntu*" will do EXACTLY what it promises:

- It will erase your **entire disk**, including all data and operating systems. All of it, gone forever. No undo. No reversal. No more option to "factory reset" Windows.
- If you want to dual-boot with Windows, choose the "*Install alongside Windows*" option. If that option is not presented, then see ["Install alongside" option missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/)
- If you are a bit hazy on what the term '*re-partitioning*' means, then stay away from the "*Something Else*" option.
- See the [Ubuntu Desktop Tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop) for a complete list of settings and options.

If you are nervous about installing Ubuntu (lots of first-timers are!), you can install a Virtual Machine application on your current operating system, spin up a disposable Virtual Machine, and practice installing Ubuntu on that disposable VM.

- How to install and use a Virtual Machine on whatever current operating system you use is beyond the scope of this answer. Any search engine will happily recommend a few good tutorials for you.
- Your Windows product key is tied to your motherboard. You can reinstall Windows on your hardware by downloading, creating, and booting from a (free) Windows installer. Reinstalling Windows is fairly easy, (though a bit tedious).

Comment: I voted to reopen this question.

Answer (score 0):

It would delete it, it's like partition formatting. So you cannot access Windows again. However, files can be restored from disk with utilities such as `photorec`, because data is not overwritten, but the "references" to the files are gone when formatting a partition.

So if you want to "securely delete" your Windows, you will need to overwrite that partition.
If you don't, you won't be able to access Windows but most files can still be restored.

Comment: Don't count on photorec to restore files. And if the OP is installing Ubuntu, then a great deal of the files *will* be overwritten, which will make them irrecoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I don’t disagree with the other answers to this question there is a bigger picture. If you erase and install you will not be able to revert to exactly the same state. However you can always make a Windows install usb and do a completely fresh install. It should even remember your product key and activate. You might need to download some drivers from the manufacturer but that is about all to revert to a fresh setup of windows.