# Ubuntu won't install alongside Windows 10 + broken GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I've been having some problems.

First I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 fine and then, after a Windows update, GRUB stopped working and I could only boot into Windows. After getting frustrated trying to get the boot repair tool to work I gave up and decided to reinstall Ubuntu.

Then, in the installer, it says 'This computer currently has Windows Boot Manager on it.' and there is no option to install alongside Windows. I have tried turning off EFI with no success.

[image]

I would like to know, seeing as I have now erased my Ubuntu partition, how to get Ubuntu and Windows dual booting again and also how to fix GRUB the next time Windows updates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using) and [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/q/343268/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to AskUbuntu.
In Windows you can see if the Ubuntu partition is still there with the disk manager. It should be there.
The 'problem' is that Windows Boot manager has taken over our booting again. We have to make Grub2 our boot manager again. 
When you boot you press the function key to enter the UEFI boot manager ( F10 or another depending on the motherboard ). In there choose Ubuntu again as first boot. 
When you have safed the settings you should reboot into the Grub2 again.
Also make sure is that Secure Boot is not enabled when your system is installed while it was disabled. 
Shut of FastBoot and Hibernation in Windows ( some updates change all these settings ).

Comment: This is true, I managed to get Ubuntu installed and GRUB working by selecting the 'something else' option and allocating all the partitions. You are right

Answer (score 1):

This issue could be caused of multiple reasons but Here are Couple of solutions that can help

You can try each of these solution to solve this problem.

**1)**

Check your **boot Sequence**(or boot priority) [*you can press function key as per your system, but f2 works for most of the motherboards*].

Reason : Sometimes windows grub doesn't work and it doesn't provide you the options for booting, if that is the issue you are facing,

**reordering the boot sequence** can help you.

2)

If that's not your issue and if installing Ubuntu is necessary you can just edit the **partition table by your own** while installing.
Because **you already have Windows operating system that has EFI partition**(one EFI partition is enough and necessary for any pc), creating partition table with only **/boot** and **/home** file system while installing ubuntu OS can fix your pc with **dual boot**.

for any further query you can simply contact me on **telegram** [@sms000](https://t.me/sms000)